# How to create joins in visual designer with many to many relationship

Tags: 2sxc

So I have 3 Data Types. A district can represent more than one county and a county can have more than one district.

### County

CountyName (String)

### District

DistrictName (String)
Countys (Multi Select Dropbox)

### Candidate

Name (String)
DistrictName (String)

I want the template to generate

**County A**

-->*District 1*

--->John

--->Bill

--> *District 2*

----->Susan

**County B**

-->*District 1*

---->John

----->Bill

--> *District 3*

----->Jack

----->Jane

---

Is there any way to use the visual editor and or Razor to achieve the many to many relationship needed for this?

Thanks!

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's what I did ... I ended up pulling the full queries then using  value filters inside nested loops.

It would be really nice if we could simply pass parameters from razor to a sqldatasource but since that doesn't seem to be available we get something like this:

```
@using ToSic.Eav.DataSources

var allCounties = App.Query["Counties"]["Counties"];
var allHouseDistricts = App.Query["Districts"]["MDHouseDistricts"];

@foreach (var thisCounty in AsDynamic(allCounties.List)) {
@thisCounty.CountyName

@{
var someHouseDistricts = CreateSource<ValueFilter>(allHouseDistricts);
someHouseDistricts.Attribute = "DistrictCounties";
someHouseDistricts.Value = thisCounty.CountyName;
someHouseDistricts.Operator = "contains";
}

@foreach (var thisHouseDistict in AsDynamic(someHouseDistricts.List)) {
@thisHouseDistict.HouseDistrictName
}
}
```

Here is the page that we built: 
https://www.mdrealtor.org/Legislative/Resources/Home-Ballot